# Getting value form input type hidden

Tags: html

I am using input type hidden for getting hidden data in URL. Here is my code

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="kcc-product">
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="kcc-manufacturer">
```

When I am using it, I am getting URL as `&post_type=kcc-product&post_type=kcc-manufacturer`

But I need it like: `&post_type=kcc-product&kcc-manufacturer`

Just I have to remove `**post_type=**` from URL. I tried with

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="kcc-product">
<input type="hidden" name="" value="kcc-manufacturer">
```

But, it is not working. How can I remove `**post_type=**` from URL? Any Ideas?

Comment: can you live with `post_type=kcc-product,kcc-manufacturer`?  You should probably take a moment to look @ how form submission works and how URL query strings are formatted.  You can also do something like `kcc-product=&kcc-manufacturer=` as well.

Comment: To get a URL like you this you need to have a form field (hidden or not) named `kcc-manufacturer` with no value. This is probably not what you want. So, I'd suggest to re-evaluate what you need and how you use the submitted values on the server. You could use jQuery to "assemble" the URL, but again, you must be doing something wrong on the server if you're expecting this value.

Comment: I tried with name kcc-manufacturer, But it is generating: &post_type=kcc-product&kcc-manufacturer=

there is an extra "=" I don't need it

Comment: Can you explain why you need the URL like this and how you use the data on the server? What you want is not possible by the spec for URL query strings.

Comment: I am trying to create a search form in wordpress, that will search only two custom post. 

If I get value like this &post_type=kcc-product&kcc-manufacturer it will work. 

Anyway, I've fixed it: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-advanced-search-form-in-wordpress-for-custom-post-types/

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="kcc-product">
<input type="hidden" name="post_type[]" value="kcc-manufacturer">
```

try this. Both value of post_type will be avilable in `$_GET['post_type']` as an array.

Answer (score 0):

Not that I am advocating this approach but ..

why don't you just have one hidden field variable instead of both?

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="kcc-product&amp;kcc-manufacturer">
```

That will produce the url you are after "&post_type=kcc-product&kcc-manufacturer"

Comment: When I use one hidden filed like this

'<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="kcc-product&kcc-manufacturer">'

it is not generating & symbol in URL. It is showing like: &post_type=kcc-product%26kcc-manufacturer

I mean generating %26 instead of & symbol.

Comment: Sorry, It is not generating & symbol in URL. Used your code, it is generating &post_type=kcc-product%26kcc-manufacturer

Answer (score 0):

First thing is, there should not be two hidden fields with same name.
So, You can remove one extra hidden field and make them as one. And then write as below:

```
  <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="kcc-product&kcc-manufacturer">
```

Otherwise, if you use two hidden fields, it considers as two separate parameters and shows as two separate parameters.

Otherwise specify method="POST" in form tag, it will automatically doesn't show in url.

I guess, it might helps.

Comment: I am sorry, it is generating &post_type=kcc-product%26kcc-manufacturer

No & symbol, only generating %26 in the URL.

Comment: specify method="POST" in form tag

Comment: you mean, after using post also, is it visible in url?

Comment: Have you tried like below:     <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="kcc-product&amp;kcc-manufacturer">. If use like this, how the data is visible in URL?

Comment: Yes, I need search query will visible. I am tried with your code. It is generating: &post_type=kcc-product%26kcc-manufacturer

Comment: As per my knowledge, it is not possible to get '&' in value to show in url. Because, the parameters separation happens based on the '&'. So, if it gets the '&' in a value for a parameter, the server will get confuse while decryption the parameters and values. It may not able to get what is the parameter and what is the value. That's the main reason, it doesn't show '&' in parameter value. That's why the '&' is becoming to URl-encoding. So, at server side we can process the value for getting '&', after getting from parameter.